# Apache FileItem to byte array?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm using,

```
org.​apache.​commons.​fileupload.​FileItem
```

I want to upload a file using JSP Servlet using,

```
<form action="someAction" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Is there a way to convert this file/item to a byte array? Currently, I have done in my servlet,

```
        List<FileItem> multiparts = upload.parseRequest(req);
        for (FileItem item : multiparts) {
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                //Custom class need byte array as the file's content
                CustomClass doc = new CustomClass();
                //Need to set byte array value to this
                doc.setValue(byte array);
                item --> byte array????
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html) (emphasis is mine):

> After retrieving an instance of this class from a `FileUpload` instance (see `#parseRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)`), you may either request all contents of the file at once using **[`get()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#get--)** or request an `InputStream` with **[`getInputStream()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getInputStream--)** and process the file without attempting to load it into memory, which may come handy with large files.